# Attribute duplicated in libraries

Tags: android, gradle, android-library

I want to use those two libraries:

- https://github.com/stepstone-tech/android-material-stepper
- https://github.com/ganfra/MaterialSpinner

This is my *build.gradle*

```
dependencies
    {
        .
        .
        .
        implementation 'com.stepstone.stepper:material-stepper:4.3.1'
        implementation('com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:2.0.0') {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
        }

    }
```

Building gradle failed with the following message:

> Error:(252, 5) error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/ms_errorColor' with config ''.
>
> Error:(252, 5) error: resource previously defined here.

I realised that both libraries used the same prefix and eventually created the same attribute...

Is it possible to work around this problem and use both libraries?

**EDIT:** I created an issue on both github just to let them know this little problem occured.

Comment: Did you get a fix for this yet?

Comment: @MueyiwaMosesIkomi Nope, had to download the library and edit the attributes...

Comment: Same, had to download and fix it myself...